# Add codes to vmlinuz

Tags: linux-kernel

When I use the vi editor to add some codes to `/vmlinuz` I see it in a bad format. It seems a binary file.
I am going to improve security and add extra steps for checking password.
How can I edit `vmlinuz`?

Comment: Why do you want to edit the vmlinuz bzImage binary? BTW, is (normally) compressed.

Comment: You might be able to achieve the result you want by editing script(s) that are called when Linux boots. Look in `/etc/*.d`.

Comment: `vmlinuz` only contains the kernel. It has nothing to do with password checking. I'm afraid you're still far from the point where you could do anything to improve security.

Answer (score 3):

You should get the source code for the kernel, patch that and recompile. Changing a compiled binary is extremely difficult to do by hand and errors are easy to make.

Comment: And it's even harder to manually change a *compressed* compiled binary!